# Docker Error : You installed esbuild on another platform than the one you're currently using

Tags: docker, dockerfile, automated-tests, cypress

I ran my container for the first time on Cypress10 (on Mac) and I got the following error message. I’m trying to distinguish if this a docker issue or it’s an issue that my dev team have to resolve. If this is a docker issue how do I resolve it?

Here's a [quick video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c3iws8vp1qtwhvc/Running%20the%20docker%20container.mov?dl=0) explaining the issue in detail

Docker file configuration:

```
FROM cypress/included:10.4.0

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN npm install

RUN $(npm bin)/cypress verify

RUN $(npm bin)/cypress
```

Error Message:

```
You installed esbuild on another platform than the one you’re currently using.
This won’t work because esbuild is written with native code and needs to
install a platform-specific binary executable.

Specifically the “esbuild-darwin-arm64” package is present but this platform
needs the “esbuild-linux-arm64” package instead. People often get into this
situation by installing esbuild on Windows or macOS and copying “node_modules”
into a Docker image that runs Linux, or by copying “node_modules” between
Windows and WSL environments.

If you are installing with npm, you can try not copying the “node_modules”
directory when you copy the files over, and running “npm ci” or “npm install”
on the destination platform after the copy. Or you could consider using yarn
instead which has built-in support for installing a package on multiple
platforms simultaneously.

If you are installing with yarn, you can try listing both this platform and the
other platform in your “.yarnrc.yml” file using the “supportedArchitectures”
feature: https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc/#supportedArchitectures
Keep in mind that this means multiple copies of esbuild will be present.

Another alternative is to use the “esbuild-wasm” package instead, which works
the same way on all platforms. But it comes with a heavy performance cost and
can sometimes be 10x slower than the “esbuild” package, so you may also not
want to do that.

at generateBinPath (/e2e/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1815:17)
at esbuildCommandAndArgs (/e2e/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1901:31)
at ensureServiceIsRunning (/e2e/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2065:25)
at Object.build (/e2e/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1956:26)
at bundleOnce (/e2e/node_modules/@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor/src/index.js:24:6)
at Object.cypressESBuildFilePreprocessor [as handler] (/e2e/node_modules/@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor/src/index.js:61:14)
at invoke (/root/.cache/Cypress/10.4.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/lib/plugins/child/run_plugins.js:43:18)
at /root/.cache/Cypress/10.4.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/lib/plugins/util.js:59:14
at tryCatcher (/root/.cache/Cypress/10.4.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
at Function.Promise.attempt.Promise.try (/root/.cache/Cypress/10.4.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/method.js:39:29)
at Object.wrapChildPromise (/root/.cache/Cypress/10.4.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/lib/plugins/util.js:58:23)
at Object.wrap (/root/.cache/Cypress/10.4.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/lib/plugins/child/preprocessor.js:47:8)
at RunPlugins.execute (/root/.cache/Cypress/10.4.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/lib/plugins/child/run_plugins.js:152:29)
at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/root/.cache/Cypress/10.4.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/lib/plugins/child/run_plugins.js:257:12)
at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:526:28)
at process.<anonymous> (/root/.cache/Cypress/10.4.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/lib/plugins/util.js:33:22)
at process.emit (node:events:526:28)
at emit (node:internal/child_process:938:14)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)
```

Comment: Encountered the same error with the `sanity` setup in a non-dockerized env. I tried the good old `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` inside the project, and the build or dev worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the other errors you show in the video, but this error should be solved by adding a `.dockerignore` file (see the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file)) beside your `dockerfile` with the following contents:

```
node_modules/
```

This should prevent the copying of the node_modules folder to your docker image and `RUN npm install` should install the correct ESLint version.